# highlight text inside a div or span using typescript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typescript

I am trying to highlight the text inside a div / span automatically when the page loads.

I am able to highlight text in a read-only textbox but, the text inside a div / span, is not working.

I am using typescript in my application.

**Fiddler:** http://jsfiddle.net/5zWad/75/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="ABC" />
<div>
  <span>
    this is a span
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  this is a div
</div>
```

**JS**
    Inside a typescript method,

```
//WORKING
$('input').select();

//NOT WORKING
$('span').select();

//NOT WORKING
$('div').select();
```

I looking for a suggestion that works with typescript.

Any suggestion / direction will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I tried the suggestion provided by "Get Off My Lawn" but, typescript is not recognizing the createTextRange() and showing error.

Comment: @Anthony that probably won't work as the OP probably wants to highlight it so the user can do `ctrl+c` to copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: I have updated the question and title

Answer (score 1):

The `.select()` event is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes.